# Aborting git stash pop

Tags: git

I have a repo where I saved a stash on branch B which is ahead of branch A. Then on branch A I popped that stash and now have the problem of merge conflicts

I would very much like to abort the whole operation and perform stash pop on branch b. Is there a simple way to do it?

I do not care about the working copy in my directory too much as it was clean before popping the stash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a

```
git stash save stashed_changes_from_b
```

when you are on branch A. This will create a stash which in essence is the same stash you had when you ran git stash on branch B. Now, A will not be having any of the changes and will be in the state it was before you did git stash pop. You can now do whatever you want with branch A and when you are done and want to pop the stash onto branch B, you simply checkout branch B and do a

```
 git stash pop.
```

(I use git stash save  to give my stashes a name because it helps me know at a glance what that stash contains when I run

```
git stash list.)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about your working copy, you can just `git reset --hard` back to `HEAD` to get back to `A`'s most recent actual commit (and then swap to `B`).